# Hybrid : OpenMPI + OpenMP on a cluster

Tags: openmp, openmpi, hybrid

I solve numerically some Ordinary Differential Equations.

I have a very simple (conceptually), but very long computations. There is a very long array (~2M cells) and for each cell I need to perform numerical integration. This procedure should be repeated 1000 times. By using OpenMP parallelism and one 24-core machine, it takes around a week to do this (which is not acceptable).

I have a cluster of 20 such (24-core) machines and think about Hybrid implementation. I want to use MPI to pass over these 20 nodes and at each node use regular OpenMP parallelism.

Basically, I need to split my very long array to 20(nodes)X24(proccs) working units.

Are there any suggestion of better implementation or better ideas? I've read a lot on this subject and I've got impression, that sometimes such hybrid implementation does not necessarily bring a real speed up.

May be I should create a "pool of workers" and "feed" them with my array or something else.

Any suggestion and useful links are welcome!

Comment: More information required for any good answer: what communication is necessary between processes or threads running individual computations ?  With OpenMP those communications are typically disguised as shared memory accesses.  In other words, how close to *embarrassingly parallel* is your computation ?  Finally, do you have a job management system, such as Grid Engine, installed on your hardware ?

Comment: I need to contact our sys admin to find out about any Grid Engine, but so far I've never heard about such engine on our computing cluster.

Comment: I need to contact our sys admin to find out about any Grid Engine, but so far I've never heard about such engine on our computing cluster.

So, for a moment let's consider there is NO any grid engine.

My program is extremely embarrassingly parallel(!). Suppose you need  
to apply some function on each cell of a huge array in any order of cells. (i. e. for a given matrix(array) of arguments(angles), compute a matrix of Cos of each argument(angle)). But computing time of "Cos" and the size of the matrix are very large.

Answer (score 0):

If your computation is as embarrassingly parallel as you indicate you should expect good speedup by spreading the load across all 20 of your machines. By `good` I mean `close to 20` and by `close to 20` I mean any number which you actually get which leaves you thinking that the effort has been worthwhile.

Your proposed hybrid solution is certainly feasible and you should get good speedup if you implement it.

One alternative to a hybrid MPI+OpenMP program would be a job script (written in your favourite scripting language) which simply splits your large array into 20 pieces and starts 20 jobs, one on each machine running an instance of your program.  When they've all finished have another script ready to recombine the results.  This would avoid having to write any MPI code at all.

If your computer has an installation of Grid Engine you can probably write a job submission script to submit your work as an *array job* and let Grid Engine take care of parcelling the work out to the individual machines/tasks.  I expect that other job management systems have similar facilities but I'm not familiar with them.

Another alternative would be an all-MPI code, that is drop the OpenMP altogether and modify your code to use whatever processors it finds available when you run it.  Again, if your program requires little or no inter-process communication you should get good speedup.

Using MPI on a shared memory computer is sometimes a better (in performance terms) approach than OpenMP, sometimes worse.  Trouble is, it's difficult to be certain about which approach is better for a particular program on a particular architecture with RAM and cache and interconnects and buses and all the other variables to consider.

One factor I've ignored, largely because you've provided no data to consider, is the load-balancing of your program.  If you split your very large dataset into 20 equal-sized pieces do you end up with 20 equal-duration jobs ?  If not, and if you have an idea how job time varies with inputs, you might do something more sophisticated in splitting the job up than simply chopping your into those 20 equal pieces.  You might, for instance, chop it into 2000 equal pieces and serve them one at a time to the machinery for execution.  In this case what you gain in load-balancing might be at risk of being lost to the time costs of job management.  You pays yer money and you takes yer choice.

From your problem statement I wouldn't be making a decision about which solution to go for on the basis of expected performance, because I'd expect any of the approaches to get into the same ballpark performance-wise, but on the time to develop a working solution.

Comment: Great answer!!! I was sure, that for shared memory, it's better to use OpenMP than MPI, but now I think just to rewrite my program as you suggested only in terms of MPI and let the program to access to all available processors on the entire cluster (20X24). Regarding the size of my array, it is flexible, since it is a grid and I can adjust its size to the the size of the computing units in order to get maximal load.